# Can I use existing APP service in XYZ tenant for web api registered in Azure AD B2C of ABC tenant

Tags: multi-tenant, azure-web-app-service

I have an existing App Service in XYZ tenant. Previously my API was in XYZ tenant and using that App Service of same Tenant, now I have moved my API from Azure AD of XYZ Tenant to azure AD B2C of ABC Tenant. can I use existing App Service of a different Tenant(XYZ) in this scenario to publish the API. Can App Service be a multi-tenant.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding your app service which hosting your APIs is under subscription of XYZ tenant and use Azure AD App in this tenant to auth your APIs. And now you want to use Azure AD B2C App in another tenant(ABC tenant) to protect your APIs .

Yes, of course you can do that.You can use Azure AD apps belongs to other tenant(including Azure AD b2c tenant) to protect your APIs hosted on App Service . Which Azure subscription that your  App Service belongs to just means you will be charged on that subscription, it has nothing to do with the business logic with your code on app service.

If you want to do so , at the code level , there will be some differences compared to using Azure AD applications if you use Azure AD b2c applications to protect your APIs . 
This sample page will be helpful for you to modifying your codes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples

If you want to design your APIs as multi-tenant by Azure AD b2c, this doc will be helpful : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom

If there is anything unclear , pls feel free to let me know and if my suggestion is helpful , pls mark me :)

Comment: Hi , pls mark me if my suggestions are helpful , if you have any further concerns , pls feel free to let me know : )